# how to fetch record in one table with self join in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

in categories table 3 fields

```
id   categoryName    parent_id
1    Architect       0
2    Vendor          0
3    Res Architect   1
4    Electrician     2
```

in my model

```
public function parent()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id');
}

public function children()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

in controller

```
SELECT t2.categoryName FROM categories t1, categories t2
WHERE t1.id = id 
AND t2.parent_id = t1.id
```

i have no idea to fetch record with self join into one table in laravel
please help

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: how to fetch like : 
Electrician is Vendor
because vendor id is 2 and Electrician parent_id is 2

can u help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the parent relationship a little bit, it should be `parent_id` because child category reference parent category by using `parent_id` field.

```
public function parent()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

You can do it like this

Get all parent categories with its children

```
$parentCategories  = Category::with('children')->where('parent_id', 0)->get();
```

Get all child with their parent

```
$childCategories = Category::with('parent')->where('parent_id','>', 0)->get();
```

Now fetch it like this

```
foreach($parentCategories as $parentCategory){
    dd($parentCategory->children); //children for parent category 
}
```

Similarly for child categories

```
foreach($childCategories as $childCategory){
    dd($childCategory->parent); //parent of child category
}
```

Fetch Electrician (As per your request in comment)

```
$electrician = Category::with('parent')->where('id', 4)->first();
dd($electrician->parent); //this will be Vendor
```

**OR** if you want to fetch all child of Vendor then

```
$vendor = Category::with('children')->where('id', 2)->first();
dd($vendor->children); //children of vendor
```

Comment: but sir how to fetch like :
Electrician is Vendor